# I need the buttons to be always aligned at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I need the buttons to be aligned at the bottom of the box, regardless of the amount of text. I've tried with flex, but still not working. 
this is the html. so 3 boxes displaying side by side and I want the buttons to be always aligned to the bottom (so they are all vertically aligned)

html:

```
 <div id="" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center mb-5 building-block">
            <div class="white-bg box no-margin">
              <div class="news-container" id="news1">
                <div class="news-image"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="list-container">
                <h5 class="title dark-violet">
                  title
                </h5>
                <p class="body-text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce finibus purus vitae tellus elementum, quis aliquam orci finibus. Maecenas velit odio, aliquet id augue eu, tristique dignissim risus. magna, quis feugiat sapien commodo sit amet. Donec sodales nulla sapien, eu luctus sem tempor at.
                </p>
                <a
                  class="btn btn-sun btn-shadow"
                  href="http://www.google.com"
                  role="button"
                  target="_blank""
                  >Read more</a
                >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your css. And what version of bootstrap your using. Are you repeating this same div three times?

Comment: Yes I am.


.news-container {
min-height: 200px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
padding: 30px 10px 0px;
position: relative;
}


-webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 20px;
min-height: 420px;
padding: 0px;
}
.news-image {
min-height: 200px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
padding: 30px 10px 0px;
position: relative;}

Comment: .list-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.btn-sun, .btn-sun:hover {
background: #f7ab1b;
border: 1px solid #f7ab1b;
color: #ffffff;
}

Comment: @Sara Could you select one  of the answers as the approved one?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you well.

```
 <div id="" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center mb-5 building-block">
            <div class="white-bg box no-margin">
              <div class="news-container" id="news1">
                <div class="news-image"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="list-container">
                <h5 class="title dark-violet">
                  title
                </h5>
                <div class="body-text-div">
                  <p class="body-text">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce finibus purus vitae tellus elementum, quis aliquam orci finibus. Maecenas velit odio, aliquet id augue eu, tristique dignissim risus. magna, quis feugiat sapien commodo sit amet. Donec sodales nulla sapien, eu luctus sem tempor at.
                </p>
                </div>
                <div class="button-container">
                 <a
                  class="btn btn-sun btn-shadow"
                  href="http://www.google.com"
                  >Read more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and in your css:

```
<style>
.list-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.body-text-div{
  background-color: #c0c1c3;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.button-container{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

You can increase "max-height" as much as needed.
This will always take the button to the bottom.

Comment: hey, thanks for this solution. It doesnt work :( the button gets out of the main container. :\ thanks

Answer (score -1):

use this instead of `<a>` tag and use it inside a div so that its in a block element:

```
<div>
    <center><a class="btn btn-sun btn-shadow" href="http://www.google.com" role="button" 
    target="_blank"">Read more</a></center>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you introduced the obsolete and deprecated `<center>` element?

Comment: Super, so use a different element that remains valid, whether under HTML 4, HTML 4.1 or HTML 5; there's no reason whatsoever to use a non-valid, obsolete element that's been deprecated (and therefore removed from the spec).